# Adding collision and score in basic p5js game

Tags: p5.js

i'm quite new to P5js and i'm working on detecting the avatar (named 'bird' in the code) and the obstacle (ellipse)

i'm having quite a hard time with this, i try to get the score added or deducted as the avatar hits obstacle or ellipse.

I have tried various ways but still the code was always messed up.So I'm asking for advice. Any assistance is appreciated. this is the code that i have for now:

```javascript
let wW = window.innerWidth
let wH = window.innerHeight


let x = 0


let posX = wW/2
let posY = wH/2
let spdX //+0.5 -> -0.5
let spdY 
let isBallMoving = true 
let degree = 0
let myBalls = [] 
let maxBall = 20 
let bro


function preload() {
  bro = loadImage('images/bro.png');
}


function setup() {
  createCanvas(wW, wH);
//set timer 1000ms=1sec


  bird = new Bird();



  angleMode(DEGREES)
  ellipseMode(CENTER)
  // ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 50, 50)

  for(let i = 1; i < maxBall; i++) {
      let ball = {
          posX: random(wH,wW),
          posY: random(0,wH),
          size: random(4,16),
          spdX: random(-4, 4),
          spdY: random(-1, 1),
          hue: random(0, 360)
               }
      myBalls.push(ball)
  }

}

function draw() {
  background(120);



  bird.update();
  bird.show();

  stroke(255)
  strokeWeight(4)
  ellipse(x, 200, 100, 100)
  x = x + 3

  if (x > wW) {
    x = 0
  }

  degree += 0.5

  for(let i = 0; i < myBalls.length; i++) {

    //detect  x
    if (myBalls[i].posX >= wW || myBalls[i].posX <= 0) {
        myBalls[i].spdX *= +1
    }
    //detect แกน y
    if (myBalls[i].posY >= wH || myBalls[i].posY <= 0) {
        myBalls[i].spdY *= +1
    }
    //animate
    if (isBallMoving === true) {
    myBalls[i].posX += myBalls[i].spdX
    myBalls[i].posY += myBalls[i].spdY
    }

    myBalls[i].size = 40
    noFill()
    strokeWeight(3)
    stroke(myBalls[i].hue, 80, 360)//120

    //bubble
    ellipse(myBalls[i].posX, myBalls[i].posY, myBalls[i].size,myBalls[i].size)

    if (myBalls[i].posX > width) {
      myBalls[i].posX = 0;    
}


if (myBalls[i].posX < 0) {
  myBalls[i].posX = wW - 3;    
}


if (myBalls[i].posY < 0) {
  myBalls[i].posY = wH - 3;    
}

  }

  this.collidemyBalls = function(){
    this.life -= 1

  }

}

function Bird(_pos, _vel, _score, _life){
  this.pos = _pos
  this.vel = _vel
  this.score = _score
  this.life = _life 
  this.y = height/2;
  this.x = width/2;

  this.gravity = 0.7;
  this.lift = -12;
  this.velocity = 0;

  this.show = function() {
   imageMode(CENTER)
    image(bro,this.x, this.y ,160, 70)
   /* fill(255);
    ellipse(this.x, this.y, 32, 32);*/
  }

  this.up = function() {
    this.velocity += this.lift;
  }

  this.update = function() {
    this.velocity += this.gravity;
    // this.velocity *= 0.9;
    this.y += this.velocity;

    if (this.y > height) {
      this.y = height;
      this.velocity = 0;
    }

    if (this.y < 0) {
      this.y = 0;
      this.velocity = 0;
    }

  }

}

function keyPressed() {
  if (key == ' ') {
    bird.up();

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Stack Overflow isn't really designed for general "how do I do this" type questions. It's for specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions. You'll have much better luck if you point to a specific line of code that's behaving differently from what you expected. But I'll try to help in a general sense.

The best thing you can do is [break your problem down into smaller steps](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) and take those steps on one at a time. Start over with a blank sketch and show a single rectangle and a single circle. Then add some basic [collision detection](http://happcoding.io/tutorials/processing/collision-detection) code that prints a message to the console when the shapes are overlapping. You'll probably want to imagine a bounding box around the circle and use rectangle-rectangle collision detection. Then add a second circle. Then get it working with an array of circles. Then add your images in.

You shouldn't be trying to do everything all at once, or implementing all of your logic in your final sketch. You should be isolating each step and only working on one small piece at a time. Then if you get stuck, you can post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/) along with a more specific technical question. Good luck.